# tkinter: how to accept multiple inputs from the user one by one in a pop-up?

Tags: python, tkinter, popup

So I have a root widget, I want to create a pop-up that accepts the number of teachers teaching each of say 10 subjects. (something like 3 math teachers, 2 English teachers etc)

And I want to use that number that the user has entered in a for loop. Any suggestions on another way I could stucture accepting multiple inputs one-by-one would be greatly appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

def start():
    popup = Toplevel() #this doesnt throw an error when kept in main part of program, why?
    popup.geometry('400x300')
    for x in ['chem','math','eng']:
        accept(x)

def accept(sub):
    global entry, label2
    label2=Label(popup,text="Enter the number of {} teachers".format(sub))
    label2.pack()
    entry=Entry(popup) #entry box
    entry.pack()
    nextb=Button(popup,text='NEXT',command=lambda:nextentry(sub))
    nextb.pack()

def nextentry(subject):
    global entry
    n=int(entry.get())
    l=[i+1 for i in range(n)] #i basically want the int of the input, i'm getting an error helppp??
    for k in range(n):
        allsec[k].append(subject+str(choice(l)))
    entry.delete(first=0,last='end')

#----------MAIN----------#
allsec=[[],[],[]]
root=Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
l1=Label(root,text='USER INPUT')

button=Button(root,text='Start',command=start)
[i.pack() for i in [l1,button]]

root.mainloop()
print(allsec)
```

Comment: Try to append the `Entry` instances into a list and access them by using their index, followed by `.get()`. Right now, your `n=int(entry.get())` will return values only form the last instance created.

Comment: I hope you got that I meant `entry` instances that you created in `accept(sub)` and then use `list_name[index].get()` to get the value of the same [Based on the error in your previously deleted comment]. But it's still unclear why do you want to have 3 buttons and clear the entry every time for taking number of teachers, why not have a single button and iterate through the list to get the value of all the entries at once?

Comment: yes, ive made the changes, it works as expected. those clear statements arent really required, they are leftovers of an old code that i didnt remove, Thanks again!